# Jar file is corrupt after downloading

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just created small jsp file in which I am downloading a jar file from weblogic server that is installed in my computer through eclipse using the following piece of code which I grabbed from net. But when I try the jar file, it says it is corrupt. The sizes of original and downloaded jar files are identical. I can download and open text files using the code. What is wrong in the code?

```
  <%    
  String filename = "Words2.jar";   
  String filepath = "C:\\Users\\OD00259\\Desktop\\";   
  response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" +  
  filename + "\"");   

  java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream
  (filepath + filename);  

  int i;   
  while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
  out.write(i);   
  }   
  fileInputStream.close();   
  %>
```

Comment: Have you tried redownloading it a second time? Sometimes files get corrupted during download.

Comment: Don't forget to call `out.flush();` and maybe `out.close()`. You should probably also send the file length.

Answer (score 0):

Try Change the content-type to application/java-archive. Also set the content-length header to include the size of the file.

Also, I would recommend you to use some checksum tools like md5sum for verifying the file downloads comparison instead of relying on the size to compare.